# Extract text from href link in html in xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I want to extract html text from a html object using xpath. I don't need the href. Is there a way I can specify that?

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/xxk/xxk?trk=ppro_cprof">Munich</a>
```

I have used the following but it gives me the full text between a. Can anyone tell me how to extract text with xpath.

```
//section[@id='location']//h5/a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `text()`:

```
//section[@id='location']//h5/a/text()
```